# Create a template with ITemplate for a datalist

Tags: asp.net

How to create a new template e.g with divs for a DataList programmatically with ITemplate 
or any other similar way?

Answer (score 1):

try using [CSS Adapters](http://www.asp.net/CSSAdapters/WalkThru/WalkThrough.aspx) they replace with css, the traditional tables based layouts in asp.net controls. it might be easy to change the layout by tweaking an adapter rather than writing a full fledged control.